# Creating a separate access_log and error_log for Apache2

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I would like to set up Apache2 so that it logs to a separate log for access and error. App1 is located at /var/www/ and App2 is located at /var/www/app2. How should I approach this problem?

Should I create a virtual host for each directory or will a .htaccess work for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Put the ErrorLog directive in the site configuration `/etc/apache2/site-available/mysite` :

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

Eventually you can replace `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` with an absolute path.

If you want more complicated things, you can use the rotatelogs utility like:

```
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs logs/access.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 10M" common
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs logs/error.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 10M"
```

While you're at it, you can specify an additional pre/postfix to "access/error" string to customise this per site.

Answer (score 0):

An .htaccess file won't work, sorry. You need to put it in a logfile.

From the [config docs at apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog)

```
CustomLog Directive
Description:    Sets filename and format of log file
Syntax: CustomLog file|pipe format|nickname [env=[!]environment-variable]
Context:    server config, virtual host
Status: Base
Module: mod_log_config
```

I haven't tested to see if it works in  blocks though. You might want to experiment with that. Failing that, they have an example of *SetEnfIf* and *CustomLog* based on env vars which would work for what you wanted.

Comment: You mean config file, not logfile, I think?